# Endianness affecting memory loads in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

Upon reading the disassembly of code I wrote in C I found the `.word` and `.byte` directives and I was wondering what exactly they do.  If I have the following piece of code in ARM

```
some_data:
    .byte 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 20
```

and I execute the following piece of code

```
movw r1, #lower16:some_data
movt r1, #upper16:some_data
ldrb r2, [r1, #0]
```

Assuming the processor is in little endian mode, what would be the contents of `r2`?  Would it be `0x01` or would it be `20`?  What if I use the `.word` assembler directive instead like the following

```
some_data:
    .word 0x01020304
```

Comment: You're loading a byte so endianness doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes but the 4 bytes have to be stored in a certain order right?  What if the assembler directive was `.word` instead?

Comment: Is there a reason why this question references the C tag?

Comment: You could answer this yourself by assembling and hex-dumping in a single-byte format (e.g. `hexdump -C foo.o | less`).  Then you'd see what order the bytes are really in.  Or similarly with gdb, use `x /4xb some_data` to dump the four bytes separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the LDRB instruction the CPU endianness doesn't matter. It always reads the byte at the given address. For your `.word` example, if the assembler is in little-endian mode then the first byte of the word 0x01020304 is the least significant byte or 0x04.

Comment: Can the assembler and processor be in opposing "memory modes" (little endian and big endian)?  I am just curious because you mentioned the assembler being in little endian mode and not the processor itself

Comment: @Curious The assembler doesn't know what mode the CPU will be operating in when the code it is assembling gets executed. If even if its run on the same computer, the CPU's endian mode could change, at least in theory. Generally however this isn't a problem since pretty much all ARM CPUs run in little endian mode.

Comment: Strictly, one _might_ stumble across an ARM7 or ARM9 in word-invariant big-endian mode, for which this answer isn't true, but for the sake of sanity let's keep pretending that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an RTM thing.  The older pre-armv6 arms were word invariant or BE-32 as arm calls it now.  armv6 and later is byte invariant.  See the arm docs and the assembler docs.

You are asking two questions here, or maybe three or more.

1) You seem to be curious as to what an ldrb returns in either mode.  Armv6 and later is byte invariant, so that means no matter what mode you are in the same byte instruction (ldrb or strb) operates on the same byte in memory in the same way.  armv4 and armv5 are word invariant meaning a word operation (ldr, str, stm, ldm) operates the same way independent of the endian setting.  implying that the byte operations on those architectures IS the thing that is affected by endianness and it in fact is.

2) what does my assembler do with a .word or .byte and how does it place that in memory.  Assembly language is defined by the assembler, the software you are using.  There isnt a standard and even if there were, doesnt mean folks have to follow it.  If you assume the arm documentation is the standard then why does the most popular assembler for arm not follow it?  The assembly language is defined by the assembler, so what assembler are you using, what specific version, what specific command line options or directives, and if source based what options used when compiling that tool?   We cant answer other than to say just try it...Takes about the same if not less time than asking the question online, and certainly if you add in the time waiting for an answer.

so.s

```
.byte 0x01,0x02,0x03,20
.word 0x01020304
```

and then try it

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o 

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   14030201    strne   r0, [r3], #-513 ; 0xfffffdff
   4:   01020304    tsteq   r2, r4, lsl #6

arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.o -O binary so.bin
hexdump -C so.bin 
00000000  01 02 03 14 04 03 02 01                           |........|
00000008
```

so,one of many possible answers to the question of what does my assembler do.

3) so what happens runtime, well that is really question 1 but you put the two together, how did I assemble my code and how did it place data in memory, combined with what mode am I in on what architecture for a particular instruction.

And without writing any of the above, the answer to your question is "it depends" assuming your nomenclature for what r1 holds is an aligned address at the beginning of some_data (lower two bits zero) and some_data is aligned on a word boundary. (despite what you think ALL arm architectures support unaligned accesses, but they support them differently depending on architecture ldrb is not unaligned but the tool may not care, depending, and place an unaligned .word which would change the answer).  Then ldrb will either return a 0x01 or 0x04.  depending on architecture, mode at the time of execution, and assembler.  You as the programmer are responsible for all three.  cant change the architecture but you know which one you are running on, the other two are 100% programmer, directly or indirectly.

And the second half of the experiment of course is to just run the program on the hardware and see what you get.

Comment: and yes the tools do need to know and match your runtime endianness choices.  armv4 and armv5, word invariant, all words are little endian.  Instructions and data.  armv6 and later, byte invariant, words change endianness data vs instructions so you need to tell the assembler this (compilers call assemblers generally so tell the compiler to tell the assembler) so that it produces little endian instructions and big endian data.  Otherwise when you put it all together it doesnt work.

Comment: and lastly probably the whole point of your question. if on armv6 or later and you want to access something as bytes it likely does matter whether you use .byte or .word depending on your assembler and settings.